How many users does this forum has?
I am interested to know some information about this forum.
How many users use this forum?
What is the total number of posts on this forum?
What is the total number of topics discussed on this forum?
Please, provide any links related to the statistics of the forum.

How many users use this forum?
72000+
What is the total number of posts on this forum?
23000 questions + 33000 answers = 59000+ post
What is the total number of topics discussed on this forum?
I think post and topics are the same things, unless you are talking about the comments ?
Here is where you can see the data: https://data.stackexchange.com/ (search bitcoin)
